# Splitting work across microservice instances with dynamic partitions

Tags: microservices, partitioning, worker

I have a table in DB for "messages to be sent". Message ordering for same destination is important.

For instance:

```
create table outbox (
    id int serial,
    destination varchar
    payload varchar
)
```

Currently I have a thread which does `select * from outbox order by id`, and because ID's are ordered, I can group it by destination and send.

Now I want to make it a separate microservice but not sure about how to handle this if I have to scale it.

Answer (score 1):

That's going to scale as far as the DB can scale (because you're putting the burden of synchronizing on the DB).

Note that your IDs are globally synchronized, when you really only need the synchronization per destination.  You can get pretty far by sharding the outbox table by destination: create `N` outbox tables and consistently map a given destination to a given outbox table.  You can grow the number of outbox tables as needed, as long as doing so doesn't result in a change in which outbox table an already-existing destination uses (this can be satisfied by having a table tracking which outbox table to use for a given destination: entries can be added to that table by hash modulo number of outbox tables).  At the limit, as you scale this out, you might end up with 1 outbox table per destination.

The above is implementable in anything.

That said, the significant ordering for message sends requirement is strikingly similar to the actor model of computation (e.g. most, if not all, actor implementations provide a guarantee that if actor A sends messages X, Y, Z to actor B, actor B will receive those messages in the order they were sent).  Many actor model frameworks (e.g. Akka on the JVM, Akka.Net, Orleans, Lagom, Cloudstate, Ray(?)) support a notion of sharding actors across a cluster and using event-sourced persistence, which will manage a lot of the aspects of what I outlined above for you.  So it might be worth investigating that approach rather than trying to implement all that yourself.